# What is the purpose of extrausers?

Tags: linux, security, nsswitch

Can someone explain the purpose, and benefits, of having an additional and separate *extrausers* user database in certain Linux systems (such as [in Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/libnss-extrausers) or [in Ubuntu Core](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/admin/libnss-extrausers))? Why is not the standard `/etc/{group,passwd,shadow}` enough?

Comment: Please tell, where these extrausers are?

Comment: Normally located at **/var/lib/extrausers/{group,passwd,shadow}**.

Comment: I don't have it.

Answer (score 1):

Debian's libnss-extrausers package makes it very easy to combine users and groups from two sources:

I use my private home PC and laptop regularly to remotely mount file systems from the sec=krb5 NFS file server of my university department. In order to see and use in commands like `ls -l`, `groups`, `chgrp`, `cd ~user/`, etc.  the user and group identifiers associated with files, these need to be listed in the local getent/nsswitch database. I have my private family-member users in `/etc/passwd`. I don't want to use LDAP on a private home PC or laptop, as this would cause inconvenient delays when the LDAP server is not reachable (when the VPN to the university department is down). So I simply use a script that regularly copies all users and groups in the department's LDAP server in `/var/lib/extrausers/{group,password}` on my private machines.

The `/var/lib/extrausers/` mechanism makes this extremely convenient: my script can simply overwrite all files in there, without having to modify `/etc/{group,passwd}` and having to keep track where which entry in there came from. I could even maintain these extra users and groups there via an automatically updated deb package.

I'm currently looking for a similar solution for macOS, and I wish it too had `/var/lib/extrausers`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well it can be usefull when you want to mix "manualy" maintened passwd files an automated deployment of "immutables" local users with tools like chef/puppet/ansible for exemple (there are other way yes).

Comment: There is a better explanation in Debian bug #791661.